# Render-Dot is not working with Node.JS to convert dot graph to SVG

Tags: node.js, svg, graphviz, dot

Hello I am trying to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/render-dot) dot parser and multi format converter e.g. SVG or PNG in Node.JS, but the problem is that they provide a JavaScript compliant syntax which is

```
import {renderDot} from 'render-dot'
```

but above line gives error, cannot import outside module

I tried to convert it to node variant

```
let renderDot = require('render-dot')
```

still with no luck Node.JS is not compiling, how I can convert dot graph to SVG in Node.JS any alternatives would be highly appreciated.